What is the meaning of this Zaman Ali quote?

“Creating individuality, which creates and protects others' individualities is good.”
― Zaman Ali


Please give a precise reference of the quote and clarify the context; thanks.

Individuality as in being unique is to be, sensu amplissimo, encouraged as a good thing.
